# Python using an if in a single line for statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to know if it is possible to use an if/else in the following format, so I can avoid looping through the list twice to check the keys:

```
 test_dict = { d['name'] : d['type'] for d in object_list }
```

what I wanted to do was something like:

```
 test_dict = { d['name'] : d['type'] for d in object_list if 'name' in d and 'type' in d }
```

It would be nice if I could raise my own key error if one doesnt exist.

=======================

edit.

This is for a json list of dictionaries I am converting to a dictionary as each dictionary in the list should only have two values. But I want to check these two values exist, i.e. so name wasnt called nane by mistake

```
[ { "name":"test","type":"test"},{ "name":"test2","type":"test2"},{...}]
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  What happened when you tried this?

Comment: `d` looks like a `dict` not `list`. Hence there won't be any loops for lookups.

Comment: Have you tried running this? What happened? Did you get an error?

Comment: You could accidentally overwrite keys in `test_dict` if d['name'] is not unique.

Comment: You could always use d.get('name') and d.get('value), then get rid of the None key and any keys with None value at the end.

Comment: "You could accidentally overwrite keys in test_dict if d['name'] is not unique." Good spot, but this is actually fine as far as the functionality is concerned

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6:

```
test_dict = { d.get('name') : d.get('type') for d in object_list if d.get('name') is not None and d.get('type') is not None }
```

In the interpreter:

```
>>> object_list = [ { "name":"test","type":"test"},{ "name":"test2","type":"test2"}, {'test':'bust', 'type':'busty'},{'name': 'test3', 'loser':'soloser'}]
>>> test_dict = { d.get('name') : d.get('type') for d in object_list if d.get('name') is not None and d.get('type') is not None}
>>> test_dict
{'test': 'test', 'test2': 'test2'}
>>>
```

If you want the KeyError, you'll need to throw out the comprehension and just do a traditional loop with a try-except in each iteration.  Any Exception in the comprehension will throw everything out with no way to catch and handle the offending key.